# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2023

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

**Summary**: elementary OS Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/3) on **March 7** to bring in 2 more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on March 7, users can [nominate themselves](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/3). Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On March 14, if there are 3 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 3 candidates, we'll simply appoint the candidates so we can get the team up to 3 mods. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, we'll announce the results on Meta on March 22 (or March 29, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.